# best way to get insights into 2 categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a pandas dataframe with all categorical variables. eg. below is a sample from dataset:

| Gender | Contract | Buy Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Y | Y |
| Male | N | Y |
| Female | Y | Y |
| Female | N | Y |

Is there any efficient dynamic way to compare categorical variables and get a percentage number with respect to hue variable? eg. below is the desired output.

| Gender | Buy Product | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Y | 50% |
| Female | N | 50% |

and

| Contract | Buy Product | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | Y | 50% |
| N | N | 50% |

Comment: Why does Buy Product start at all Ys then become 50%s?

Comment: Its just a sample :-)

Comment: I guess the question is... do the values in Buy Product mean anything? Or are you just trying to get the percentage of Y/N in contract per Gender value?

Comment: thanks @HenryEcker! made corrections.

Comment: What @HenryEcker's comment is getting at is your question seems to be "please tell me how to do categorical variable statistics" :) Stack Overflow is here to help you implement your specific idea or answer specific questions. See the [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page. You might have more luck getting guidance about how to analyze this type of data on [statistics stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But either way I'd recommend being way more specific about the structure of your data and what you're hoping to learn about it. Good luck!

Comment: If on the other hand, you're simply trying to compute a simple statistic such as the percentage Y for each Gender/Contract, then try to be really specific about this in your question.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: seems the OP is simply looking for a table showing some  conditional dependences.

Comment: JavaProgrammer: what does *"percentage number with respect to hue variable"* mean?? Please state your questions clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear for me but what you probably need is `groupby` and `value_counts`.

For instance:

```
>>> df.groupby('Gender')['Buy Product'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100

Gender  Buy Product
Female  Y              100.0
Male    Y              100.0
Name: Buy Product, dtype: float64
```